# Blender 2.82 Eevee smoke problem (density)

Tags: smoke-simulation

I use Blender 2.82 for 2 days now. I have real problem to get nice results with smoke. I cannot generate dense smoke. I tried everything. Nothing helps. I had no such a problem with previous version (2.81). 
The smoke is very weak, thin (not dense). Changing density in Principle Volume Shader DOES NOTHING. I tweak it from 1 up to even 1000000. The smoke is still weak and very transparent. I checked once more similar situation in earlier version and density (in volume matarial) changes a lot. Even with small values. I cannot make the visual change in 2.82

[blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lhfA9nILl46wgYoPaIJchRDT9BJt7i92)

[image: weak smoke]

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem until I tried to solve yours one.
I have found that the most helpful is decreasing Volumetrics End Distance or increasing Volumetrics Samples amount.
[image: Picture1]

For some reason I couldn't make the smoke render with OpenVDB cache. So I changed it to modular Uni Cache and made a full bake.

[image: Pic2]